# Rpy2: refactor an R magic cell into Python function

Tags: python, r, rpy2

Now I use Rpy2 in Jupyter notebook to fit von Mises distribution, the code is

```
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
%R require(movMF)

%%R -i dir_data,n_vM_dir -o theta,alpha
result = movMF(dir_data, n_vM_dir, nruns = 10)
theta = result$theta
alpha = result$alpha
```

- Input: `dir_data`,`n_vM_dir`
- Output: `theta`,`alpha`

It will take the `dir_data`, `n_vM_dir` variables in Python and pass them into R. After the fitting, `theta` and `alpha` will pass back to Python, so I can use them in later analysis.

Now, I want to refactor the code into a Python function, so I can reuse it, how can I do it?

---

I can do this so far

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
# pass dir_data, n_vM_dir into R
robjects.r('''
    result = movMF(dir_data, n_vM_dir, nruns = 10)
    theta = result$theta
    alpha = result$alpha
''')
theta = robjects.r('theta')
alpha = robjects.r('alpha')
# Return theta, alpha
```

I can access the data through `robjects.r`, the main problem is that

- I don't know how to pass the data stored in Python to R (`dir_data`,`n_vM_dir` in this example).

I've read the docs in http://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/introduction.html

I find the variables are created by

```
from rpy2.robjects import FloatVector
ctl = FloatVector([4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14])
```

But this looks very complex compared to the `R magic` in jupyter notebook.